# reroute htaccess when index in any subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have the following rewrite set up in my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)$ index.php?controller=$1&cmd=$2&params=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?controller=$1&cmd=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?controller=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So for example blog just rewrites to index.php?controller=blog or blog/show/32 rewrites to index.php?controller=blog&cmd=show&params=32 etc etc.

I want to shift all my site into a subfolder called testing so need to update my htaccess to suit. Not worried about rerouting to the folder i.e. i'm not bothered about typing www.example.com and it landing at /testing/index.php, I want to type www.example.com/testing/ and it land at index.php which it does but the other rules seem to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move this .htaccess to the subfolder, together with the files, it will work just as expected. You don't need to change anything. If you have a `RewriteBase` directive in your .htaccess, you have to update it to reflect the new path.

Answer (score 0):

Keep this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?!testing/).*)$ testing/$1 [L,NC]
```

Keep this rule in your /testing/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testing/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)$ index.php?controller=$1&cmd=$2&params=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?controller=$1&cmd=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?controller=$1 [L,QSA]
```